# Interval Range Count value in a Textbox

Tags: vb.net

I know it was an answer to my question but I can't find it if you can help me with the link (here was the answer on the site). I want to display in Textbox (if I have for example)

```
Textbox1.Text=3,4,8,17,19,23,24,27,31,32,41,42,48,60,63,66,69,75,78,79
```

I Want Output:

```
Textbox2.Lines(0) = 3 - Count Number of interval 1-10
Textbox2.Lines(1) = 2 - Count Number of interval 10-20
Textbox2.Lines(2) = 3 - Count Number of interval 20-30
Textbox2.Lines(3) = 2 - Count Number of interval 30-40
Textbox2.Lines(4) = 3 - Count Number of interval 40-50
Textbox2.Lines(5) = 1 - Count Number of interval 50-60
Textbox2.Lines(6) = 4 - Count Number of interval 60-70
Textbox2.Lines(7) = 3 - Count Number of interval 70-80
```

Comment: I suggest that you spend a bit of time in the Help Center and learn what constitutes a valid question here at SO.

Comment: TextBox.Text is a String. Literal strings are enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some help:

You need to convert your list of numbers from a string(s) into integers:

```
Dim lst As New List(Of Integer)

For Each item As String In Textbox1.Split(","c)
    lst.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Item))
Next
```

Then you can use LINQ to query for ranges:

```
Dim count = lst.AsEnumerable().Count(Function(x) x>= 1 AndAlso x < 10)
```

You need to use AsEnumerable otherwise the standard Count() hides the LINQ extension method Count(Func)

Best of luck!